# Lottery Outcomes

Tags: probability, statistics, lotteries

I'm trying to calculate the chance multiple people (https://www.usamega.com/powerball/drawing/2021/1/16) might win second prize in the Powerball lottery and while I can calculate the chance that one might win (1 in 11,688,053.52) I'm not sure how to apply this to multiple winners.

Let's say ten people win the second prize (match 5 and not Powerball), how would I calculate the likelihood of this occurrence in a field of ~10,000,000 players?

Comment: Binomial distribution or Poisson approximation to it.

Comment: Let's say $P$ is the probability of a *given* person winning the second prize lottery. Then the probability that ten people out of 10,000,000 win the second prize is ${{10,000,000}\choose{10}} \times P$. For the sake of actually computing things you'll probably want to consider approximations though.